# AngularJs how to call the value of a radio button?

Tags: angularjs

```
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Glossy: </label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Yes</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">No</label>
        </div><br>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script>
     //document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date();
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("verify", function ($scope){

        var verifydate = function(){
          var name = $scope.ss;
            if(ss.checked){
                z = Date.parse(Date());
                z = z + 86400000;
                var mydate1 = new Date(z);
            }
        };       


    });
</script>
```

`How do you call the value of a radio button in angularJS and store it in a variable. I am trying to make this function in the controller so that i can print the delivery date in the span but I am not able to?

[image]

Comment: Please click on the link to see the image of the code

Comment: Please post the code instead of a picture. It will be easier to read and modify

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Please paste the code in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the necessary information in the documentation for [`input\[radio\]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Every input should have the same `ng-model` but with different `value` or `ng-value`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.shirts = "A magnificient t-shirt with a unicorn on it !";//used with ng-value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="radio" id="poster" name="optradio" ng-model="option" value="poster">Posters
  <input type="radio" id="coffee" name="optradio" ng-model="option" value="coffee">Coffee mugs
  <input type="radio" id="shirt" name="optradio" ng-model="option" ng-value="shirts">T-shirts

  <p>You choosed : {{option}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is want to do is if the particular radio value is checked it should show the delivery date next to the radio button but I am struggling . I want to create a function which will add 3 days to the present date when one radio button is checked.Please advice

Comment: This is another problem. SO is a 1 to 1 question-answer. If you have another problem you should ask another question

Comment: actually i just wanted to know how to use that value of radio button in a function in angularJS controller. I am sorry I am new to stack exchange so I am not completely aware of the protocol